# Transitioning from academia to industry

Tags: career-path, industry

I am currently doing post doc at the University of Toronto with quite a renowned scientist and my tenure will end in the next month. I have been awarded Marie-Curie Fellowship with Research Centre (Beamline specifically) as the host. Will the Marie-Curie Fellowship make me a more attractive candidate for industry R&D jobs in India since I would want to settle in India eventually.

Comment: Seems a fairly personal decision. Pros and cons either way, up to you to make a decision based on your situation and values.

Comment: We cannot tell you which job to take. Is there some missing information that might help inform your decision? For example, "Will the Marie-Curie Fellowship make me a more attractive candidate for industry jobs in Canada" might be a good question (although even this example would not a good fit for Academia.SE, since few of us hold industry jobs in Canada).

Comment: "preparations for a non-academic career" are not [on-topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here -  the site caters to academics and careers in academia, industry really isn't in our scope.

Comment: @BryanKrause - given the number of questions around this topic, we might consider accepting some, or a canonical question. Seems like many students/post-docs don't get good advice locally...

Comment: @JonCuster Pretty hard to get advice about industry if you're only asking people in academia, whether on this site or locally. I'm not sure it's a good fit for a canonical question, but it's something that could be raised on Meta.

Comment: Some of use have been through academia, but are not _in_ academia...

Comment: I proposed an edit to narrow the question to industry R&D jobs, since these are technically in scope. Still, "industry R&D in India" is a big place, so the question may still be difficult to answer. If you are not pursuing R&D jobs, that's fine, but then your question can't be answered here, unfortunately.

Comment: A degree means something, but beyond that what do you have to offer? This might be your initial exploration of careers outside academia, and, if so, I wish you best of luck. There are many, many opportunities to work, though possibly not at your postdoc area. Cast a very wide net, the world has plenty of researchers.